# wildcards in dynamic outbound ssl endpoints IBM WEBSPHERE

Tags: websphere-8

I want to configure outbound endpoints in my ssl configuration. I am using Websphere 8.5.5 traditional.

I want to reach address of the following type

https://host1.some.address
https://host2.some.adress

I tried specifying it with the  pattern
*,*.some.address,*

But does not seem to be working

Comment: Finally found the solution. It was answered in an IBM forum. However this works from Websphere 8.5.5.13 onwards only https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=badb53e6-8523-4394-87bc-a921ceb13a61&ps=25

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have run into a bug in the filter matching that is fixed by https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI86143.  Please try moving to 8.5.5.13 to see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: Nope. The talks about matching hosts it should not have. I wanted to know if stating *,*.some.address,* would work

Comment: Well the correct filter would be *,.some.address,*,   The wild cards for the endpoint and port values.   Looks like your missing the first wild card.

Comment: So it seem my wild character (asterisks) is not showing up above.   I'm trying to say \*,.some.address,\* is the correct format.  But will not work properly without the apar I mention.

Comment: ok. Not sure why the asterisk gets removed. I will try with the apar. we are in 8.5.5.12

Comment: BTW, I added the explicit address as pipe separated list. *,host1.someaddress.com,*|*,host2.someaddress.com,*. Even this did not work. I had add a new entry with the Same SSL setting.

Comment: A piped list should work too \*,host1.someaddress.com,\*|\*,host2.someaddress.com,\*.   When giving the full address we have to match exactly to what is in the outbound socket call.  Sometimes what is making the outbound call changes the host into an ip address.  I suppose that could be the case for you,  can you try an ip address just to see if that matches.

Comment: No. We are trying to connect to a resource inside a  public cloud. we don't have static IP addresses to these resource. In fact we can't even resolve the IP address from the endpoint names

Comment: I guess I should ask what are you using to make the outbound call?  It is possible that you are using something that bypasses the WebSphere SSL.  It can happen if you are using something that creates it own SSLContext instance.

Comment: I am using Azure SDK apis to make outbound calls.

Comment: I am not familiar with how Azure SDK works.  If it creates its own SSLContext instance then WebSphere SSL will be ignored.  Trace both JSSE trace and SSL trace could give us an indication.   Perhaps you should open a pmr to have it investigated.

Comment: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN "CN=*.some.adress" was sent from target host:port "host2.some.adress:443".  The signer may need to be addd to local trust store "/appl/was/profiles/node/config/cells/<vmname>-cell/trust.p12" located in SSL configuration alias "NodeDefaultSSLSettings" loaded from SSL configuration file "security.xml".

Comment: The extended error message from the SSL handshake eception is: "PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build  valid CertPath.; internal cause is:java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root,OU=CyberTrust,O=Baltimore, C=IE is not trusted; internal cause is:java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error".

Comment: The IBM support assigned to us says we cannot use wildcards in hostnames. Which doesn't make sense. Is their any documentation which can prove it otherwise?

Comment: Well it sounds like you need the signer from host2.some.adress:443 added to the trust.p12 file.   YOu can get that by using the retrieveFromPort option on the WAS console.  Navigate to the keystore object for /appl/was/profiles/node/config/cells/<vmname>-cell/trust.p12.  Go to Signer Certificates,  click Retrieve from port fill in the host, port and a alias name to give the cert.  Retrieve the information then save it.

Comment: we have already done this. my question is do we have a generic solution? Where we import the certificate and say it should be applicable for all hosts with the url pattern https://*.someaddress,com:443/*    Everytime we have to add a new destination, we have to go and configure the endpoints. There is a lot of redtape involved in getting this done in prod environments. Hence the question

Comment: As long as your outbound calls are using a WebSphere SSL configuration then using dynamic outbound selection should work.  I do not know what you are using to make outbound connection to tell you if all your outbound calls will get picked up by the filter.   Do all the hosts that match your filter have the same trust?   You will need to establish trust with each host you connect to.

Comment: Yes. we have added the same trust store. One more updated, the pipe separated list works. Some issue with my testing. so as of now in my outbound configuration looks like "\*,host1.someaddress.com,*|\*,host2.someaddress.com.*|\*,host3.soneaddress.com,*" As I said,earlier, I am using Azure sdk. I can send to the above addresses. If tomorrow, I have to add a 4th destination. I will have to add it to the list. Azure SDK has multiple http libraries. Some of them use the apache commons, while some use the OkHttp3 client libraries

Comment: You may run into a problem with okHttp3,  I believe it creates it own instance of a SSLContext and it will end up by passing WebSphere SSL and your outbound filter will not work.  If you are using httpClient it will work if you use the useSystemProperties() option.